# changing the parent of an entity using JPA and Eclipselink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am currently using 3 classes **A,B** and **C** that have a OneToMany relation. I want to change the parent **A1** of an entity **B1** to a new parent **A2**, the relation between **A** and **B** is oneToMany. Entity **B** has a list of **C**. All oneToMany relations are annotated with cascadeAll.
If I perform:

```
A1.removeB(B1)
B1.setA(A2) 
A2.add(B1)
```

then saving A1 and A2, using merge, instance B1 becomes a child of A2 but the children of B1 (list of child C) is removed from the database and still in cache!

Why the list C was removed from the database and is there another method to change the parent of an entity?

Comment: C seems unrelated, but this could only occur if you've made it dependent somehow on the A relationship. Show how you've mapped A, B and C, and if the C is still in the cache, check the SQL statements being issued for the operation in question (by turning EclipseLink logging on).

Comment: @Chris The relation between B and C is OneToMany with cascadeAll and orphanRemoval is true, so when you remove B1, the List<C> C1 will be removed from the database, but my question is: why list C1 has not added again to the database where we added B1 to A2?

Comment: If that is your question - show the relationship and eplicietely mention you are using orphan removal. Don't have commenters have to guess at what you've got. In this case, the addition of B1 is probably being processed before the process handling the orphan removal logic of B1 from A1, so it doesn't know to undo it. Orphan removal and private ownership is only meant for a certain situation which this isn't it, and is a waste of resources when you can easily call em.remove when you need to. Cascade merge/persist is done during em operations, while orphan removal at flush/commit time.